# PHP equivalent of nth-child

Tags: php, wordpress, css-selectors

I have a PHP array of items (WordPress posts) that I loop through to create a 3x3 grid of posts. 
Using jQuery, I apply a CSS class to the middle-column items like so:
`$('#grid li:nth-child(3n+2)').addClass('middle');`

How can I achieve this in PHP? Can I set a counter that will match `2,5,8,11, etc...`?

Comment: What about `($i % 3) - 2 == 0`?

Comment: All these complex answers below - this is the simplest and best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about loops in PHP? Without knowing more about what exactly you're trying to achieve in your PHP code, I can only suggest something like this:

```
$posts = array(); //The whatever thing that contains the posts you are concerned about
for ($i = 1; $i<=count($posts); $i++) {
    if($i == /*selector condition*/) {
        //do what you do with the targeted posts
    } else {
        //do what you do with all others
    }
}
```

(See http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp)

Little side note: You would normally start counting with $i=0 but I assume if you're talking about posts they will probably start counting at 1 and not 0.

Comment: `$posts` (WP_Query) does not implement the `countable` interface, see http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20296

Answer (score 1):

```
function nthChild($multiplier, $addition, $max)
{
    $validInedexes = array();

    for ($n = 0; $n < $max; $n++)
    {
        $idx = $multiplier * $n + $addition;
        if ($idx > $max)
        {
            return $validInedexes;
        }
        $validInedexes[] = ($idx - 1);
    }
}
```

The above function will give you valid indexes based on input.
Then in any loop match by index. use in_array function for that or anything you like.

Answer (score 0):

$my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=special_cat&posts_per_page=10'); ?>

```
$query = new WP_Query('...');
$posts = ($count = $query->post_count) ? range(1, $count) : array();
foreach (array_chunk($posts, 3) as $row => $rowIndexes)
{
    foreach ($rowIndexes as $column => $index)
    {
        $query->the_post();
        $middle = $column === 1;
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`:nth-child(3n+2)` would be:

```
$count = count($arr);
for($i = 0, $idx = 0; $idx < $count - 1; $idx = 3 * $i + 2, $i++) {
    print_r($arr[$idx]);
}
```

Granted this will only give you those specific items. If you wanted all the items and only run a block of code on those elements then I don't know.... yet.